# Understanding the Fourier Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, fourier-series

I am trying to solve the following Fourier Series problem.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1,& -1<x<0 \newline
 1, &  0<x<1
\end{cases}$$

We know that on the interval $[-1,1]$ is odd. We calculate the coefficients
$$a_0=0 , \quad a_n=0 , \quad b_n=\frac{4}{n\pi}$$

Thus,

$$Sf(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{(2k-1)\pi} \sin[(2k-1) \pi x] $$

I tried to study the same problem on Mathematica with the following code

```
f[x_]=Which[-1<x<0,-1,0<x<1,1]
Plot[f[x],{x,-1,1}]
```

[image]

```
L=2;
a[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
a[0] := (1/L)*Integrate[f[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
b[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
F[x_, Nmax_] := a[0] + Sum[a[n]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L] + b[n]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, Nmax}]
p[Nmax_, a_] := 
 Plot[Evaluate[F[x, Nmax]], {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 200]
f[x_] = If[x > 0, 1, -1];
a[n]
a[0]
b[n]
Simplify[%, n \[Element] Integers]
Table[F[0.5, k], {k, 0, 20}]
p[20,1]
```

[image]
[image]

We notice that with the exception of the first value all other values are double. Why is this phenomenon observed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the $2/L$ coefficients vs. one $1/L$ coefficient?

Comment: @J.G. Above the last plot, I have put a table with the exception of the first value all other values are double. This output made me confused

Comment: @J.G. At this particular problem, we don't have $1/L$ coefficients because $a_0$ is zero

Comment: The `Simplify` input returns $\dfrac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n\pi}$. When $n=2k$ is even, this reduces to $0$. Otherwise, when $n=2k+1$ is odd, $1-(-1)^{2k+1}=2$, hence $b_n=\dfrac{4}{n\pi}=\dfrac4{(2k+1)\pi}$.